# iOS 10, bluetooth connection from today extension / widget

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, widget, today-extension

I´m having an App with a Today Extension/Widget. This Widget has a CBCentralManager to scan for peripherals and connect to them. The scanner works fine but connecting to the device sometimes works and sometimes get´s stuck at connecting. The led at my bluetooth device lights up briefly so I see that there is some kind of communication.

The very same code works perfectly fine in the app itself just not from the widget.

When I run the widget on a iOS 9 device it also works fine!
Are there any known issues with connecting to a bluetooth device from a today extension on iOS 10?

Thanks
Stephan